# GIT: Editar una revisión de una rama local usando git rebase -i

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-rebase

¿Es posible actualizar(editar) un contenido de un commit con: "git rebase -i"? ¿Si es asi cuales serian los pasos a seguir? Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si, si se puede. Si quieres cambiar algo de la revision X, tienes que correr `git rebase -i X~` (incluir el rabo'e cochino). X deberia ser la primera revision de la lista. Dependiendo de lo que quieras, colocas una acción diferente.

- Si quieres modificar el comentario de la revision solamente colocar `reword`. Al ejecutar te va a salir el editor para que coloques el comentario que quieras.
- Si quieres modificar algo de un archivo acometido, colocar `edit`. Git se va a detener luego de aplicar esa revision. edita lo que quieras en los archivos, `git add` y luego `git commit --amend --no-edit`.
- Si quieres hacer ambas cosas, colocar `edit`. git se va a detener luego de aplicar la revision, edita los archivos, luego `git add` y luego `git commit  --amend` y te va a salir el editor para colocar el comentario apropiado.

Esto implica reescribir la historia de la rama, lo cual tiene otras implicaciones. En general no se recomienda hacer en ramas compartidas/publicas

Comment: Tengo 3 commits puse git rebase -i 1~ / git rebase -i 2~ y me arrojo: fatal: invalid upstream '1~' y fatal: invalid upstream '2~' si seria la primera revisión seria --root o algo asi?

Comment: No es por números que git va a reconocer una revision. Tienes que usar el id de la revision. Y si, si la operacion la quieres hacer en la primera revision de la rama, toca que pongas `git rebase -i --root`.

Comment: Entonces se puede usar algo asi: git rebase -i 7215767b~ (directo al id del commit) esta interesante este comando tiene muchas funciones.

Comment: si esa es la revisión a la que le quieres hacer alguna modificación? Si. Y si, rebase (en general) es muy potente.... y el interactivo te permite hacer muchos trucos.

Comment: Lo máximo! muchas gracias 

Comment: Me parece mas completo rebase "git rebase -i --root" ya que con el id o con números~ ambos me muestran el editor, con el primer comando se puede visualizar todos los id

Comment: El editor me arrojo dos comandos: You can amend the commit now, with

  git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

  git rebase --continue

Comment: Eso te puede funcionar en proyectos con historia corta. En proyectos con cientos/miles de revisiones te puedo asegurar que para modificar algo de la revisión HEAD~3 **no** vas a querer ver toda la historia en el editor en un `rebase -i`.

Comment: No se cual fue la acción que le colocaste. Si la acción fue "edit", pues edita lo que necesites del archivo que necesites, agrega al index, y enmiendas la revisión con `git commit --amend --no-edit` (el --no-edit si no quieres modificar el comentario que ya tenía la revisión) y luego del amend, ejecutas `git rebase --continue` para que el rebase siga su camino.

Comment: Luego de "git commit --amend --no-edit" le di a "git rebase --continue" y recien se guardo y donde me aparecia master paso de estar: "master|REBASE1/3" a nuevamente master

Comment: eso indica que ya terminó el rebase (te debió salir un mensaje al respecto). Verifica la historia de la rama y contenido de los archivos.

Comment: Me arrojo: Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

Comment: Parece que misión cumplida :D

Comment: exacto! Ya terminó el rebase exitosamente.

Comment: Disculpe he estado usando el rebase y en un tutorial encontré que usan el comando `git rebase master` , pero no entiendo para que usan el parámetro master, ya que dentro de rebase hay opciones delo que se quiere hacer pero no menciona el master. Gracias de antemano por la respuesta.

Comment: Usado de esa forma estas pidiendo que todas las revisiones que pertenecen a tu rama actual y que no están en la rama `master` se coloquen a partir de la punta de la rama `master`

Comment: entonces es parecido a usar un `git merge` para hacer una unión del tipo `fast-forward`

Comment: No. El resultado de un rebase _al final_ debe ser igual a hacer un merge.... pero el rebase va replicando las revisiones que pides sobre una revisión diferente a la que originalmente estaban. Y el `fast-forward` no es ni un merge ni un rebase... o sea, es un `merge`, pero sin hacer realmente un merge.

Comment: Tengo otra duda se puede unir o fusionar con otra rama usando el comando como por ejemplo: `git rebase nombreDeRama` o para unir se tiene que unir necesariamente con merge

Comment: Si te refieres a mezclar el contenido del proyecto? SI, claro... el rebase de una rama sobre otra tiene que dar el mismo resultado (en contenido de los archivos) que si hicieras una mezcla. Pero el resultado de la historia (como se ven las revisiones de la rama) no es el mismo, obviamente.